# R error x and y lengths differ

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a solution to a ODE in R, and I typed:

```
dx=0.01
x=seq(-5,5,by=dx)
A=0.5
B=1
C=-2
length(Y)=length(x)-2
Y=x*0
Y[1]=A
Y[2]=dx*B+A
for(k in 1:(length(x)-3))(C*dx^2-1)*Y[k]+2*Y[k+1]
plot(x[1:(length(x)-2)],Y,type="l",col="blue")
```

It shows me the error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Comment: Yes, `length(x[1:(length(x)-2)])` gives `999` and `length(Y)` gives `1001`.

Comment: What is the point of the for loop? It doesn't assign anything. Did you mean `Y[k] <- (C*dx^2-....`?

Comment: The plot works for me. But the order of your calls are misplaced. `length(Y)` is altered before it is created.

Comment: @PierreLafortune How could it work?

Comment: because they plot length(x) - 2

Comment: The plot, as written in the OP' question, doesn't work.

Comment: added as an answer for reference

Answer (score 0):

Lines 6 and 7 need to be switched. You can't alter the length of a variable before it is created. Also, I think you meant to assign the for loop output to a variable.

```
dx=0.01
x=seq(-5,5,by=dx)
A=0.5
B=1
C=-2
Y=x*0
length(Y)=length(x)-2
Y[1]=A
Y[2]=dx*B+A
for(k in 1:(length(x)-3))(C*dx^2-1)*Y[k]+2*Y[k+1]
plot(x[1:(length(x)-2)],Y,type="l",col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: You should say why it works: because you changed the order of 2 lines. People won't read comments.